# Does setInterval repeat?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Sorry if you think i'm asking too many questions, this will probably be my last one.
So, here's the cut. There's a button that calls the "nodeIncrease();" function and the setInterval is *supposed* to repeat, but it  doesn't do anything.
I don't know if i'm supposed to put a while (true) loop somewhere, but I tried that and it just makes my browser lag.

```
var click = 1;
var unitt = 0;
var node = 0;
var nodePrice = 10;
var nodeInterval;
function unittIncrease() {
    unitt += click;
    document.getElementById('unitts').innerHTML = "Unitts: " + unitt;
}
function nodeIncrease() {
    if (unitt >= nodePrice) {
        clearInterval(nodeInterval);
        node++;
        unitt -= nodePrice;
        document.getElementById('unitts').innerHTML = "Unitts: " + unitt
        document.getElementById('nodes').innerHTML = "Nodes: " + node + " - $" + nodePrice;
        nodeIntervalHandler();
    } else {
        alert("Inefficient amount of unitts.")
    }
}
function nodeIntervalHandler() {
    nodeInterval = setInterval(nodeLoop, 1000);
}
function nodeLoop() {
    unitt += (node * 0.1)
}
```

Comment: What is the output that you're expecting?

Comment: while(true) loop is OK if used correctly.  But if you're doing it wrong, then you hang the browser because Javascript is single threaded.  As for the setInterval, you can clearInterval but you have to provide html so we can confirm your code is correct.

Comment: `setInterval` repeats yes. But the function you are repeating `nodeLoop` doesn't do anything visually.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `setInterval` repeats until you call `clearInterval` with the interval to stop. By way of example, the following code will count to 5. `setInterval` sets up the counter, `setTimeout` sets up a single event in 5 seconds to stop the counter, and `clearInterval` stop counting.

```js
var value = 0;
var log = document.getElementById('log');

function increment() {
  value++;
  log.innerHTML = log.innerHTML + '<li>' + value + '</li>'
}

var count = setInterval(increment, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(count);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<ul id="log"></ul>
```